# two haxe versions on same linux machine

Tags: linux, haxe, haxelib

Is it possible to have haxe2 and haxe3 installed and usable at once on same linux machine? I'm trying to setup a CC server.

I have an awkward solution with symlinks: have a symlink in /usr/lib that points to haxe installation I want to use and update it manually each time I want to switch. But may be there's something more elegant?

Ideally, I'd like to run haxe3 for the third version and just haxe for the second. And of course they need to have their own set of haxelib libraries.

Comment: I'd take a look at this project: https://github.com/dpeek/hvm/ ... I'm using it to successfully switch between Haxe 3.* versions on Linux, and the maintainer is using it to switch between Haxe 2 and 3 on OSX. I remember noticing that Haxe 2 didn't work on Linux 64 at the time, but it is probably not hard to solve if you want to invest a bit of time.  I just don't use Haxe 2 any more so haven't had the need :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of some kind of closure. I've ended up using docker. No symlinks, no switches, just separate environments for different Haxe versions.